# Bound class not applying in javascript transition

Tags: vue.js

I have this element:

```
<transition v-on:enter="slideFadeIn" v-on:leave="fadeSlideOut">
    <div :style="{height: errHeight}"
    v-show="errors.length > 0"
    :class="{'height-tr': visible}">
```

With this transition:

```
    slideFadeIn(el, done) {
          $(el).slideDown( function() {
          this.visible = true;
    }); },
```

And this CSS:

```
.height-tr {
 transition: height .5s;
}
```

As you can see, I'm trying to apply a new class once the transition completes (this class animates height changes in the div). The animation works fine, and the class works fine if I apply it manually, and I've confirmed that `this.visible` is true after the animation completes - but the class isn't being applied. Anyone know why?

Comment: Why not have this class at all times, it just have `transition` property?

Comment: Because the class interferes with the javascript transition, making it horrible and jerky.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

are you using this with jQuery? Only it looks like `this.visible` is out of scope when you try and set it:

```
slideFadeIn(el, done) {
  $(el).slideDown( function() {
    this.visible = true; // this wouldn't be the vm anymore
  })
},
```

I appreciate you said the value of visible was correct, but this doesn't look like it would work so not sure how that's being set ...

does it help if you:

```
slideFadeIn(el, done) {
  var vm = this
  $(el).slideDown(function() {
    vm.visible = true; // this wouldn't be the vm anymore
  })
},
```